# Error on delete file at Windows Mobile 6.5

Tags: c#, compact-framework, windows-mobile-6.5, .net-cf-3.5

I'm working on a project for windows mobile 6.5. I am using C # with compact framework 3.5 (CF 3.5) and SDK for Windows Mobile 6.5.

My routine writes files to a temporary directory for further processing. After a few days the file is renamed and directed to a purge.

When trying to delete the file the following error occurs: **Access to the path '\Application Data\Volatile\Temp\20170822-97703.Nf.env' is denied.**

Where:

- **\Application Data\Volatile** is the default temporary directory `Path.GetTempPath()`
- **\Temp** is my temporary directory
- **20170822-97703.Nf.env** is my file.

Code:

```
const string dirTemp= "Temp";

public void PurgeFiles()
        {
            DateTime datePurge= new DateTime();
            datePurge= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7);
            var files= FindFiles();

            foreach (string file in files)
            {
                var dateAlt = Directory.GetLastWriteTime(file);
                if (dateAlt< datePurge)
                {                    
                    Directory.Delete(file);
                }
            }
        }

private string[] FindFiles()
        {
            string searchPattern;
            string dirLocal;

            dirLocal= Path.GetTempPath();
            dirLocal= Path.Combine(dirLocal, dirTemp);

            if (Directory.Exists(dirLocal))
            {
                searchPattern = "*.Env";
                var files = Directory.GetFiles(dirLocal, searchPattern);
                return files;
            }
            else
                return new string[0];
        }
```

Save file

```
public bool SaveFile(string dir, string fileName, string content)
        {
            try
            {                
                if (!Directory.Exists(dir))
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);

                string pathFile = Path.Combine(dir, fileName);

                if (File.Exists(pathFile))
                    return true; 

                //Salva os dados
                StreamWriter fileConf = new StreamWriter(pathFile);
                fileConf.Write(content);
                fileConf.Flush();
                fileConf.Close();

                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Mark the file as processed

```
public void MarkFile(string fileName)
        {
            try
            {
                string newFileName= fileName + ".env";

                if (File.Exists(newFileName))
                    return; 

                File.Move(fileName , newFileName);
            }                
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Perhaps the file is locked and will be delete-able after a restart. If you add a try/catch around File.Delete then you can try again next time.

Comment: We need to see the code that creates and writes the temp file.  It's most likely you're not releasing the file handle at that point.

Comment: Add the save and rename functions. Quando salvo o arquivo eu fecho o mesmo, mas quando renomeio o arquivo não. Isto é necessário?

Comment: Check if you can delete the file manually. Possibly you have a special char in the name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To can delete the file I changed the name of file and the line below

`Directory.Delete(file);`

for

`File.Delete(file);`